# Stop and Restart CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS3 animation that jostles around at random when I click "Play". The problem is that I have been unable to stop the jostling when I click "Stop" which what I need to accomplish.

I have tried to use both the "-webkit-animation-play-state" and the jquery .stop() function but to no avail. I think I am close but just can't quite seem to get this one.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsledervenson/2RL7w/11/) and the code is below.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sec {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 105px;
}​
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
      setInterval( function() {
      var seconds = Math.random() * -20;
      var sdegree = seconds * 2    ;
      var num = -30;
      var together = num + sdegree;
      var srotate = "rotate(" + together + "deg)";
      $("#sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
      }, 100 );
      });

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
            $("#sec").stop(stopAll);
        })

 })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sec"></div>
<br/>
<div id="play-bt">Play</div>
<br/>
<div id="stop-bt">Stop</div>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: Both solutions create and use a global variable. The advantage of my solution is that the global variable is of type boolean versus Sam's answer uses a function as the type of its global. Something to consider but of course, both will work.

Comment: @frenchie - there is a serious problem with your answer.  You never stop the interval in your code, you just prevent it from doing anything.  This means that every time you click the 'start' button, you spawn a new animation "thread".  Also, clicking the start button will activate all running threads, which will cause some serious slowdown on the page if you stop/start repeatedly.

Comment: @frenchie - also, in my answer I'm storing a number, not a function.

Comment: @SamDufel - I was wondering if there was a way with this to prohibit the speed of the jostling from doubling when I click play twice. Thanks again.

Comment: @Johan - I'll edit it into my answer below

Comment: @SamDufel - Thanks! One last question...do you know how to start the animation on "Play" after "Stop" has been clicked? I updated the above jsfiddle and when I stop the animation I can't get it to start again. I have been messing around with it for a while to no avail.

Comment: Mm, forgot to add a line originally - just set `animation = null` at the end of `$('#stop-bt').click(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterpart of `setInterval()` which is used to stop it is `clearInterval()`.  Each call to `setInterval()` returns an interval ID, which you can pass to `clearInterval()` to stop it.

So, you'll need to store the result of `setInterval()`, and clear it when you click the stop btn.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animation = null;
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
      if (animation !== null) {      // Add this if statement to prevent
         return;                     // doubled animations
      }
      animation = setInterval( function() {
        var seconds = Math.random() * -20;
        var sdegree = seconds * 2    ;
        var num = -30;
        var together = num + sdegree;
        var srotate = "rotate(" + together + "deg)";
        $("#sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
      }, 100 );
      });

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
            //$("#sec").stop(stopAll);
        if (animation !== null) {
            clearInterval(animation);
            animation = null;
        }           
    });

 });
```

Comment: Perfect! You're a life saver.